# Too many connections (New Error)

Tags: java, tomcat, connection-pooling

Ok, I change my connection factory code, I'm using PoolProperties class and now I'm getting this error:

> **Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"**

In my InsertandGetObject Method I log a message in order to test that the connection is closing and it is, I also debbug on server.

Any ideas for this issue? :s

This is my connection Pool:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws DatabaseConnectionException {

    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setName("jdbc/MetaData");
    p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name");
    p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    p.setUsername("root");
    p.setPassword("");
    p.setInitialSize(3);
    p.setMaxActive(10);
    p.setMaxIdle(8);
    p.setMinIdle(2);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);

    Connection conn = null;



    try {

        DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(p);

        conn = dataSource.getConnection();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("MSJ SQLExp: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new DatabaseConnectionException(e);

    } 

    return conn;
}
```

This is the method that close the connection:

```
    public Concept insertAndGetObject(Concept object) throws SQLException,
        DatabaseConnectionException {
    try {

        connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_CONCEPTS);
        statement = ConceptMapperUtil.setStatementParameters(statement,
                object);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
        LOGGER.debug("Inserted concept row ");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();

        if (e.getErrorCode() == SQL_INSERT_ERROR_CODE) {
            LOGGER.debug("Concept already exists!");
        } else {
            throw e;
        }

    } finally {
        object = findConceptByUniqueFk(object.dataSource.getIdDataSource(),
                object.conceptType.getIdConcept(),
                object.idMetadataVersion.getIdMetaDataVersion());
        DbUtil.close(statement);
        // connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        DbUtil.close(connection);
    }
    return object;
}
```

Comment: Not strictly to do with your question, but why are you (1) not getting the `Concept` at the beginning of the method, in order to avoid using exceptions as "normal" business logic (inserting an already existing concept is "normal" in your flow) and (2) going back to the database in the finally clause when there is a chance that a serious SQLException has been thrown, and your connection is in an invalid state?  This 2nd point may even explain your problem, though I can't tell with the info you've provided so far.

Comment: I made a few changes and now I'm getting this error, any idea?

Comment: How many requests (or simultaneos requests) your application is receiving? Your database is configured to handle how many simultaneos connections? try  increase the number of connections mysql will allow (via mysql administrator or editing my.ini)

Comment: in your finally block you call DbUtil.close twice in a row DbUtil.close(statement) -> first (using statement as parameter), and then you call DbUtil.close(connection), this time passing connection as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `new DataSource(PoolProperties)` you do not create a "DataSource object wrapping a connection" (as stated in the [ApiDocs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html#DataSource%28org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration%29)). Instead, you create a pool of connections (also mentioned in the ApiDocs, but at the top: "The DataSource simply wraps a ConnectionPool ..."). I verified this in, what I think is, the source code (see line 108 of [DataSourceProxy](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tags/JDBC_POOL_1_1_0_1/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java?view=markup)).

Consequently, closing a Connection only returns it to the pool (so it can be re-used), it does not actually close the connection (unless you see the connection actually being closed on the database server, in which case I'm wrong). Solution is to create 1 DataSource object and re-use it for each `getConnection()` call. Close the DataSource/ConnectionPool when the application no longer needs a database connection.